# Format date in Java

Tags: java, date-format

I have the following string:

```
Mon Sep 14 15:24:40 UTC 2009
```

I need to format it into a string like this:

```
14/9/2009
```

How do I do it in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (click the javadoc link to see patterns) to parse the string in one pattern to a fullworthy [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and use another one to format the parsed `Date` to a string in another pattern.

```
String string1 = "Mon Sep 14 15:24:40 UTC 2009";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy").parse(string1);
String string2 = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy").format(date);
System.out.println(string2); // 14/9/2009
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use SimpleDateFormat class to convert the string you have to a date object. The date format can be given in the constructor. The format method converts the string to a date object.

After getting the date object, you can format it in the way you want.

Comment: I tried: SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("Mon Sep 14 15:24:40 UTC 2009"); but it didn't work! I got: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'o'

Comment: You need to use the patterns shown in the table in this page: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

One liner in java 8 and above.

```
String localDateTime= LocalDateTime.parse("Mon Sep 14 15:24:40 UTC 2009", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Date d = new Date("Mon Sep 14 15:24:40 UTC 2009");
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
String s = new String(f.format(d));
```