# Variable creation in Java

Tags: java, variables

Please explain how I can create a variable in US short date format (like MM-DD-YY -> 05-12-94).

Also please explain what type of variable (is in int?) is it -> 000000001

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Perhaps you want to use java.util.Date and SimpleDateFormat variables, but it's very hard to say given the confusing bits that you've posted. Please tell us what you are trying to do, not how you're trying to do it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177291/format-date-in-java

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this isn't a "Please do this for me" service.

Comment: Please make an effort to better explain your question as it's hard to understand. Also please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I don't think this was  "please do this for me question".  It's not like the OP posted a homework assignment verbatim.  He's clearly new to the language and wants to know if there is a built in way to handle dates.  StackOverflow is about spreading knowledge about programming; this includes teaching new programmers who have a desire to learn.

Comment: +1 user112358132134. This seems like a basic, but clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `java.util.Date`.  It uses a long underneath to represent time since 1-Jan-1970 in milliseconds.

Formatting, parsing, and rendering are separate issues.

I'd do it this way:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");
formatter.setLenient(false);
Date d = formatter.parse("05-12-94");
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use a [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) or a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) as your data type to hold the instance.  You can then choose to display the date using a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), which you could configure exactly as you stated - probably a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no primitive type in Java for handling dates.  You can either keep the month, day, and year of a date in three different integers, create your own object encapsulating these three integers, or use the [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object.

The int is a primative data type in Java that stores a signed integer in two's compliment binary form.  It is 32-bits long.