# Datetimepicker value is hidden when I load the data

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, datetimepicker, java.util.date

I have the following datetimepicker configured:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'es'
    , format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    , viewMode: 'years'
    , ignoreReadonly: true
});
```

Before I save the form, I serialize it and save it without issues, but when I get the date, the value is hidden because this is in another format (YYYY-MM-DD).

How I can get the right format from Java? I use java.util.Date

Comment: How are you formatting the date now? Show your Java code.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177291/format-date-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in java using  :

```
(1) get today's date or get your db date
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

// (2) create a date "formatter" (the date format we want)
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");

// (3) create a new String using the date format we want
String folderName = formatter.format(today);
```

and pass it to model using and use this in your datepicker

model.addAttribute("heading", heading);